# estimation of this formula, whether it is non-positive

Tags: analysis, inequality

I am reading a paper which gives

$$-\frac{\cos\alpha}{2}\big [ \sum_{i=1}^N (\gamma_i^2+o(\gamma_i^4)\big ]+\sin\alpha\sum_{i=1}^No(\gamma_i^3)\leq 0$$
where $N$ in an integer that larger than one, $\alpha\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, and $\gamma_i$ is a small value.

Could someone help me to verify whether this is true?

An update:
the statement in my post is equivalent to $f(\theta^*)\geq f(\theta)$ in the [the paper](http://im.hit.edu.cn/_upload/article/files/6d/77/25fc9f684579a063e4f43a11bc4e/434fa898-12d6-43ed-b310-32db6811416f.pdf), page7 (2)

Comment: Could you add the reference to the paper?

Comment: @KingVon Sure! http://im.hit.edu.cn/_upload/article/files/6d/77/25fc9f684579a063e4f43a11bc4e/434fa898-12d6-43ed-b310-32db6811416f.pdf the statement in my post is equivalent to $f(\theta^*)\geq f(\theta)$ in the page7 (2)